# What is the best way to render 3D without a library?

Tags: actionscript-3, matrix, 3d

Let's say I want to create a 3D environment from scratch, without any sort of library.  My instinct is to create a 3D matrix (a vector, since I'm using AS3) and then manipulate objects'  and cameras' positions in the matrix.  Then I would calculate the position of the active camera and how much of the matrix it should be able to see, and render those parts of the matrix (the objects) into view.

I would, of course, have a separate matrix holding object positions for efficient access.

Is this efficient?  Will the processor be able to handle these calculations in a single-threaded AS3 application?  If not, what is a better method?

Comment: Why not use a library?  [PaperVision3D](https://code.google.com/p/papervision3d/) is a completely open source actionScript library that does all of that for you.  If you want to do it yourself, basically you want to do everything you do in any course regarding a 3D pipeline.  The fact that other viable libraries exist imply that you can make a decent AS3 3D system.

Comment: Of course I understand that it can be done, I'm asking if my suggested method is an adequate solution.  I don't want to use a library purely because I want to advance myself as a programmer.

Comment: Then study up the basics of 3D programming.  (e.g., you wouldn't use the phrase "manipulate objects' and cameras' positions in the matrix" if you know the basics - you can use a matrix **to** manipulate any object (a camera is an object for that purpose), but that's different from manipulating positions **in** a matrix).  Get some books on 3D, or find some sites - or look at a convenient open-source library that does everything you need, and learn by reading it and experimenting with it.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Please do not give PV3D as example. That library is super outdated and does not use GPU acceleration at all. In that case better go with Away3D or something similar.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Any recommendations on specific books/websites as learning materials?

Comment: @Fygo For what it's worth, I'm pretty sure the OP isn't looking for any GPU acceleration - they just want the basics of doing 3D.  The last I played with 3D in ActionScript, it was with PV3D, but since [Away3d](http://away3d.com/) is open source as well, I'd say either of them are good learning resources for OP.

Comment: @JS Honestly, no, nothing specific.  My first taste of 3D was a college course, where they taught how OpenGL's features work and the mathematics behind them.  I've never professionally used OpenGL, but I've applied that knowledge to using at least 4 other 3D libraries.  A rendering pipeline is the same concept, no matter which library you're using.  There are tons of references out there; find one that is understandable for you, and hang out there for a while.  Or pick any 3D library, and play with their "hello world" style tutorials (and then look at the underlying code).

Answer (score 0):

In Actionscript3 there are some basic 3D objects like [Matrix3D](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix3D.html), [Vector3D](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Vector3D.html), [TriangleCulling](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/TriangleCulling.html), [Utils3D](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Utils3D.html), [GraphicsTrianglePath](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/GraphicsTrianglePath.html). These objects are optimized but please don't expect wonders. I've looked into my own Engine and I can render a model with 700 faces with 20-30 fps.

A better (faster) way would be to use the GPU accelerated methods in AS3: [Stage3D](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage3D.html), [Context3D](http://help.adobe.com/de_DE/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display3D/Context3D.html). These objects are more abstracted and it's like programming OpenGL or DirectX.

So if you want to learn how 3D engines work under the hood go with option 1. Else go with option 2 or  WebGL.